# How to enable a click action on a particular row?

Tags: javascript, angular, html

```
<tr class="t-row {{selectedGoalIndex == j?'active-row':''}}" *ngFor="let goalObj of goalsList;let j=index;" (click)="getSelectedGoal(goalObj,j);">
  <td class="t-column" style="width:70%">{{goalObj.goalType.combinedName}}
    <span class="goals-doubletriangle" *ngIf="doubleTriangle==true" (click)="showDoubleTriangleUp(selectedGoal);">
      <img class="goals-icon-up" src="assets/images/doubletriangle.svg" />
    </span>
    <!-- <span class="goals-doubletriangle" *ngIf="doubleTriangle==false" (click)="showDoubleTriangleDown(selectedGoal);">
      <img class="goals-icon-down" src="assets/images/doubletriangle.svg" />
    </span> -->
  </td>
  <td class="t-column align-right" style="width:30%">
    <span class="icon-trash-o goal-delete show-pointer" *ngIf="!(isSuperAdminUser) && isEditable" (click)="deleteGoal(goalObj);"></span>
    <span class="icon-angle-right"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

this is the code i have and i want to enable the click action on the double triangle image and after clicking the `doubletriangle` down class should come  in the active row(only in the active row). How to do that?

Comment: There must have been a paste issue, because I only see half a line of code.

Comment: i have pasted the all code,can you now just look

Comment: @FebaStephan, what exactly do you mean by *"enable the click action on the double triangle image"* and when exactly do you want to enable it?

Comment: I agree with @SiddAjmera, I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you, but you need to adjust the code for your project.

```
constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
) {}

this.naviElem = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.imgclass');

this.renderer.addClass(this.naviElem, 'active');
```